# How to transpose rows to columns in Amazon Redshift without crosstab and filter

Tags: sql, pivot, amazon-redshift

I am using Amazon Redshift. I have a table which has data to move from one company to another date wise.

| Date | Current | Previous | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | A | B | 15 |
| 01-01-2021 | A | C | 15 |
| 01-01-2021 | A | D | 15 |
| 01-01-2021 | B | A | 15 |
| 01-01-2021 | B | C | 15 |
| 01-01-2021 | B | D | 15 |
| 01-01-2021 | C | A | 15 |
| 01-01-2021 | C | B | 15 |
| 01-01-2021 | C | D | 15 |
| 01-01-2021 | D | A | 15 |
| 01-01-2021 | D | B | 15 |
| 01-01-2021 | D | C | 15 |

I want the output of the table as

| Date | A_to_B | A_to_C | A_to_D | B_to_A | B_to_C | B_to_D | C_to_A | C_to_B | C_to_D | D_to_A | D_to_B | D_to_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 |

Can someone help me with the solution. I tried solution with hardcoding the companies name.

```
SELECT 
    distinct d,
    sum(A_to_B) as A_to_B,
    sum(A_to_C) as A_to_C,
    sum(A_to_D) as A_to_D,
    sum(B_to_A) as B_to_A,
    sum(B_to_C) as B_to_C,
    sum(B_to_D) as B_to_D,
    sum(C_to_A) as C_to_A,
    sum(C_to_B) as C_to_B,
    sum(C_to_D) as C_to_D,
    sum(D_to_A) as D_to_A
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            distinct date(transaction_Date) as d,
            case when current = 'A' AND previous = 'B' then sum(count) else 0 end as A_to_B,
            case when current = 'A' AND previous = 'C' then sum(count) else 0 end as A_to_C,
            case when current = 'A' AND previous = 'D' then sum(count) else 0 end as A_to_D,
            case when current = 'B' AND previous = 'B' then sum(count) else 0 end as B_to_A,
            case when current = 'B' AND previous = 'C' then sum(count) else 0 end as B_to_C,
            case when current = 'B' AND previous = 'D' then sum(count) else 0 end as B_to_D,
            case when current = 'B' AND previous = 'A' then sum(count) else 0 end as C_to_A,
            case when current = 'C' AND previous = 'B' then sum(count) else 0 end as C_to_B,
            case when current = 'C' AND previous = 'A' then sum(count) else 0 end as  C_to_D,
            case when current = 'C' AND previous = 'D' then sum(count) else 0 end as  D_to_A
        FROM table_name 
        where
            month_name in ('202101')
        group by
            date(transaction_date),
            current,    
            previous
        order by 
            date(transaction_date),
            current,
            previous
    ) 
group by 
    d
```

But looking for some dynamic solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "*But looking for some dynamic solution.*" - not possible. A fundamental restriction of the SQL language is that the number, names and data types of all columns of a query must be "detectable" before the query starts retrieving data.

Comment: Yes Amazon Redshift Cluster